# Switching kivy widgets

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I am using the Kivy python library.

I have two widgets defined.

When the program runs, I run the first widget.

When that widgets button is pressed, I want it to dissapear and be replaced with the second widget.

Here is the .kv for the two widgets

```
#uitest.kv
<TestForm>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        padding: 40
        Button:
            text: 'Hello'
            on_release: root.testCallback()

<TestForm2>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x, 0
            size: self.height, 10
```

My main python file runs the app, and returns the first widget

```
#main.py
from testform import TestForm
from kivy.app import App

class UITestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestForm()

# Main launching point
if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    UITestApp().run()
```

My first widget has a callback. This is where the code-in-question belongs

```
from testform2 import TestForm2
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class TestForm(Widget):
    def testCallback(self):
        TestForm2() # Code in question goes here. @TODO replace this widget with TestForm2 widget.
```

The idea here is to have a user interface manager. This manager doesn't run the UI like a tree, but like a list and stack. The list holds instances of all my UI Forms. The stack holds the traversal of said forms, whenever we jump to a form we push it to the stack and "render" or whatever that one.

EDIT:
I chose my answer, but in my searches I also found the Screen object: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html
Personally, the clear() and add() commands are more powerful, but the screen takes a lot of that out of your hands if you're interested. Transition effects too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is to have an interface manager widget, then you can have various widgets for your UI forms.

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

class InterfaceManager(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InterfaceManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.first = Button(text="First")
        self.first.bind(on_press=self.show_second)

        self.second = Button(text="Second")
        self.second.bind(on_press=self.show_final)

        self.final = Label(text="Hello World")
        self.add_widget(self.first)

    def show_second(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.second)

    def show_final(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.final)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return InterfaceManager(orientation='vertical')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

You wouldn't structure it like that of course. You could hold all your forms in a dictionary on the Container object and have a universal callback which provides another form by key.

```
class InterfaceManager(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InterfaceManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.forms = {}

    def add_form(self, key, form):
        self.forms[key] = form

    def uniCallback(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        # You could introduce a more elegant key
        # handling system here.
        self.add_widget(self.forms[button.text])
```

Comment: clear_widgets() and add_widget() were the secret commands I was missing, thanks a lot. No ammount of searching turned them up, only the "screen" object

Comment: [The docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html) are excellent for kivy and it's probably worth just browsing down the right hand side where all the different widgets are listed. There's loads of stuff I was trying to reinvent when I first found the library.

Comment: Can you give the same in Kivy language. Mixing kivy klanguage with python is making me confused!

Comment: @user3620828: It's probably worth  raising another question. Remember to provide examples of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to switch widgets is to let one be the full height of its container and let the second one have a height of zero. When you need to switch just swap the heights around.

Comment: Certaintly an interestin option! But I plan on having many widgets, and if I want to purge some from memory this might not be the best idea

Comment: @MintyAnt, in my own application I only have 2 widgets to switch between and this method works well for me. I'm sorry it didn't fit your use case.